# What is the pythonic way of returning sum of expressions from function?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy

I have a function `F`, defined as:

```
def F(x, A_0, A_1, phi_1, freq):
    return (A_0 + A_1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1 * freq * x + phi_1))
```

Sometimes I would like it to be expanded to this form:

```
def F(x, A_0, A_1, phi_1, A_2, phi_2, freq):
    return (A_0 + A_1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1 * freq * x + phi_1)
                + A_2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 2 * freq * x + phi_2))
```

I want to be able to expand the function to arbitrary many `sin` terms. Mathematically, I would like the function to return:

[image]

What is the pythonic way to do this?

My way of doing it:

```
def F(x, A_0, As, phis, freq):
    terms=[]
    for i, A_i in enumerate(As):
        terms.append(A_i*np.sin(2*np.pi*i*freq * x +phis[i]))
    return A_0 +  sum(terms)
```

How to do this better?

Comment: Your function differs from the mathematical expression, `enumerate(iterable, start=0)` by default starts from 0. So you'll multiply by a 0 there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and avoid creating an intermediary list:

```
def F(x, A_0, As, phis, freq):
    terms = (A_i*np.sin(2*np.pi*i*freq * x +phis[i]) for i, A_i in enumerate(As))
    return A_0 +  sum(terms)
```

With NumPy a better idea is to vectorise your logic:

```
def F(x, A_0, As, phis, freq):
    idx = np.arange(len(As))
    terms = As * np.sin(2 * np.pi * idx * freq * x + phis)
    return A_0 + terms.sum()
```

To understand how this works, note `np.sin` applied to an array returns an array of the same shape where `np.sin` is applied to *each* value.

As noted in @Oleg's comment, you probably want `np.arange(1, len(A_i)+1)` to ensure your enumeration begins at `1`.

Comment: Is `idx` really needed in the 2nd  `F`?

Comment: @Brenlla, I believe so, it's just a counter 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. That's exactly what the function in OP's question requires.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are 2 distinct `n` in the equation, the last one is a subindex. I have the feeling the 1st one (`2*pi*f*n`) was supposed to be a subindex too

Comment: @Brenlla, You might be right there, not sure though from just the question.

Comment: @Brenlla, thanks for the care; in my case the first n is not supposed to be subindex only the second (ie it should indeed be 2pi*n*f, the second one should be: ie phi_n); but this might not be the case for other people, so good point.